# Android - Reading data from health devices via USB

Tags: android, usb

Does android support reading data from personal health device via USB?If so what are the drivers and interfaces required for developing the same?

Answer (score 4):

Android has nothing built in to "support reading data from personal health device" by any means. You are welcome to create an Android device that has such support, by blending the Android open source project with your own drivers.